# python, which library to install to provide __log10_finite?

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I am running a Cython `macs2` program and the error says:

```
ImportError: ~/anaconda/envs/pytools_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MACS2/IO/BedGraph.so: undefined symbol: __log10_finite
```

Which library should I install to get this symbol? I installed `Cython` and `numpy` but it did not help.

Comment: Which Anaconda version do you use? It was a bug in 2013 that anaconda covers `libm` from usage: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/-DLG2ZdTkw0

Comment: Print output of `ldd ~/anaconda/envs/pytools_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MACS2/IO/BedGraph.so` for Linux, or `otool -L ...` if you're on Mac OS. I suppose it is something with GLIBC

Comment: @John_West Disabling anaconda's `libm` makes the program work. SO it is indeed a problem with ananconda. `conda info` says `conda version: 3.19.3`. I have been using the `pytool_env` environment since 2013. Could there a some remnants of the old version?